# Constraints disabled in Editor -> Pin

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I am trying to set constraints on UITableView using storyboard. In **Editor -> Pin** option, constrains are disabled.

[image]

Why aren't they enabled ?

**Update**: Gabbler's observation correctly states that **tableView is the topmost view, you don't have to do the pin action on it**. My purpose of setting constraints was to void leading space to tableView which comes by default when applications runs. Please check the screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Is Destination a tableViewController?

Comment: Yes it is UITableViewController.

Comment: Then the tableView is the topmost view, you don't have to do the pin action on it.

Comment: Alright. My purpose of doing that was to avoid a leading space to tableview added by default.

Comment: You mean the tableView cell leading space to the tableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `separatorInset` and `layoutMargins`. In `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

And add this method.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell     forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, will try this. But why is the default leading space appearing ?

Comment: This is a new feature for iOS8. In iOS 8, Apple added the layoutMargins property on UIView. layoutMargins takes a UIEdgeInsets value that lets you explicitly define the whitespace that your views can use to guide where portions of the interface should be placed.